# Where to store database sessions with Multi-Tenancy for Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, session, multi-tenant

I'm using the [Tenancy for Laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/) package to store each tenant's data in it's own Postgres schema, but I'm unsure where I should store sessions: In the tenant' schema, or in the central (public) schema?

I've changed the config `session.driver` to `database` and created a session table in both the `migrations/tenant` and `migrations` (central) folder, then created the following api route:

```php
Route::get('/test', function() {
    session(['key' => 'value']);
    return response()->json(session('key'));
})
->middleware(Stancl\Tenancy\Middleware\InitializeTenancyByRequestData::class);
```

Then, when I make a GET request to this route with header `X-Tenant: foo`, the session gets stored in the public schema sessions table, even though the `InitializeTenancyByRequestData` middleware has scoped the database connection to the `tenantfoo` schema.

Why does calling `session(['key' => 'value']);` save the session in the public schema, and not the tenant's?

Comment: It would be easier to manage user sessions in a single source of truth rather than track them across multiple databases.

Comment: When I wrote my application for multi-tenancy I just added additional web guards, and added a boot method in my model(s) to ensure a certain key (in my case a company_id) was put in every retrieval eloquent query. Works great.

Comment: Hi @danny, did you find away to fix this?

Comment: @SamerAjlawi I just kept the default behaviour that stores the sessions in the public schema. Works great.